# Check grammar for LL(1)?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

If I have to check a Left Recursive grammer for LL(1)  then should I check it after removing left recursion?

For example:-
S-> (L)|a
L->L.S|S

If I check after removing Left Recursion then the above grammer is LL(1).
But if I do not remove left recursion then above grammer is not LL(1).
which one is the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is, "Is this grammar LL(1)?", then the answer is "No".

If the question is, "Can this grammar be made LL(1)", then by all means remove the left-recursion.

The distinction is important because removing left-recursion does not preserve derivation order, so the left-recursion-eliminated grammar produces different parse trees. If it is being used to parse, it is not the same grammar.